# What could be stopping my WiFi printer from working?

Tags: wifi, printing, network

My iMac suddenly stopped recognising my HP OfficeJet 6500 printer over the wireless network. Previously, it worked fine for years. It works with USB, and the printer connects to the router without a problem - it just doesn't see the computer, which is also connected to the same router.

Things I have tried:

1. I upgraded the Mac to Lion (which I guess counts as a software re-install - it was previously on Snow Leopard)
2. I have completely reset the printing system on the Mac, and allowed it to re-find the printer and reinstall drivers.
3. I have reset the printer to factory defaults, and then re-connected it to the router.
4. I enabled Printer Sharing in System Preferences
5. I have installed a new router (a different brand)

In case it's helpful: the printer problem originally appeared to be part of a general network problem (I was also having trouble connecting to the internet and to AirPlay etc.). Replacing the router seems to have cured the rest, but the printer still didn't work - that's when I tried all the other things.

Can anyone suggest something else for me to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more thing you could try :

1. Uninstall all HP printer driver software using the HP uninstaller in Applications > Hewlett-Packard.
2. Reboot / restart your mac.
3. Reset the printing system via : Sys Prefs, Print & Fax
4. Right (control) click in the rectangle listing your printers and then choose Reset Printing System.

CAUTION : The above steps will delete all of your printers.

1. Select the plus sign to re-add it. Look for the printer, select it and wait until the "Add" button becomes available. Click it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I already did that (step 2 - forgot to mention that it also included uninstalling the HP software). The only thing I didn't do was reboot during the process. I'll give that a go. Thanks.

Comment: Yep - that did it! So the full steps seem to be resetting the printer to factory defaults, uninstalling all HP software, reseting the Mac's printing system, rebooting the Mac, unplugging the printer and plugging it back in, and then starting from scratch! Phew :)